# Recurly PHP client. How to customize error messages?

Tags: php, recurly

I'm trying to customize error messages.
For handling errors i used "try/catch" block according to [this](https://dev.recurly.com/page/php#handling-errors) Recurly documentation, like this for example:

```
try {
  $account = Recurly_Account::get('my_account_id');
  $subscription = new Recurly_Subscription();
  $subscription->account = $account;
  $subscription->plan_code = 'my_plan_code';
  $subscription->coupon_code = 'my_coupon_code';
  /* .. etc .. */
  $subscription->create();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
  print $errorMsg;
}
```

I wanted use code in catch block like this:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
  $errorCode = $e->getCode();
  print $myErrorMsg[$errorCode]; // array of my custom messages.
}
```

But getCode() method always returns zero for all possible errors.

My question for Recurly Team (or who there in this theme):
How i get error code for errors? Or please explain me how i can resolve this topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the PHP Client on Github and you search for "throw new" which is what is done when an exception is thrown you'll see that they don't set the exception error code the second parameter of the exception constructor method.

**Recurly PHP Client on Github:** https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=throw+new

**PHP Exception documentation:** http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Therefore, you'll either need to catch more exceptions based on their name
i.e.

```
catch (Recurly_NotFoundError $e) {
  print 'Record could not be found';
}
```

OR

look at the exception message and compare it

```
catch (Exception $e) {
  $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
  if($errorMessage=='Coupon is not redeemable.')
  {
    $myerrorCode=1;
  }
  //Add more else if, or case switch statement to handle the various errors you want to handle
  print $myErrorMsg[$myerrorCode]; // array of my custom messages.
}
```